# Kill child processes when parent process is killed when using mutiprocessing.pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

My main.py creates a pool and starts doing some processing infinitely. When main.py is killed i want to all processed in pool to get stopped. Does it happen automatically?

main.py

```
def start_live_trader(ticker):
   while True:
     //dosomething
     sleep(60)

pool = Pool(50)
results= pool.map(self.start_live_trader, self.tickers)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, no. You have to set a death signal for the child process to die when the parent does using:

`PR_SET_PDEATHSIG`

Comment: What is `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG`? On what platforms is this available? How do you actually "set a death signal." You could improve your answer by not leaving these questions unanswered. Right now I would not find your answer particularly useful without doing a lot of research.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not happen automatically. However ...

If you are running under Linux where you can issue the `kill` command, which seems to be the case, I would program my main process to handle that signal in the following way:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep
import signal
import sys

def foo(i):
   while True:
     sleep(60)

def endup(*args):
    print('Recieved SIGTERM', file=sys.stderr)
    pool.terminate() # kill the child processes
    sys.exit()

pool = Pool(2)
# Issue call to signal after the pool has been created
# so that the child processes do not inherit the handler.
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, endup)
results = pool.map(foo, [1,2])
```

You can then do: `kill -15 process-number`